# Can't create or import a project in vue ui

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have typed "vue ui" in cmd and the cmd told "Starting GUI Ready on http://localhost:8000".However,when I switch to creating or importing, the loading line is always flashing and I cannot change the folder.
No error message is returned but I cannot go ahead.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's unclear why you're located in system32. For starters, try to start it at the path where you have write access.

Comment: I created successfully on a folder in disk E 2 month ago,but now I don't know why it is blocked in system32.

Comment: So I think I have write access but I don't know why the path is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it after trying for a week.

type

```
npm install -g @vue/cli-init
```

in the command line

then vue ui is OK.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem is in the fact that it's defaulting to C:\Windows\System32. I was having the same problem and realized it was because I was opening a command prompt (which defaults to this directory) and simply typing `vue ui` from there. This directory has no write access though.

**Solution:** Open a command prompt, navigate to something with write access (i.e. `cd C:\Users\YourUserName`), and start `vue ui` from that directory. Should work fine from there.